# Windows Server 2003 - Block port on localhost

Tags: localhost, windows-server-2003-r2, port

We have a misbehaving daemon running on one of our Windows 2003 Servers. It telnets into `localhost:5115`

I have a feeling that if I can stop it from telnetting into localhost I can get it to fail gracefully.

Any ideas how I can block `localhost` port `5115`? I'm guessing no, because the loopback adapter is not a 'real' adapter as it is in *nix.

OS is Windows Server 2003 R2

Comment: This sounds very much like a band-aid solution. Why not fix or replace the problematic process?

Comment: @John - Absolutally correct - it's a bad solution, and a bandaid, but it's pretty much my only option at the moment. It's a 10-year-old piece of software, and we do have the latest version but the work involved in upgrading is outside of my available time at the moment.

Comment: is there anything responding on that port? If there is can you stop that process? Alternatively, perhaps you could create a dummy one to do so and hopefully satisfy the problem process. Poking around the Windows firewall sure doesn't look too promising.

Comment: @John - yeah, there's a process running on that port already but maybe I could stop that process, start another one on the same port, and then start the original process - that way it won't be able to bind to the port...

Comment: Ditto what John said, also if you use cygwin netcat `nc -l -p 5115` you can see what the daemon is sending and maybe then even configure it to respond that causes the graceful failure. (assuming it's a legible protocol...)

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you can install a firewall software to block the specified port. Or you can go into the TCP/IP properties to enable TCP filtering - and specify the allowed ports which will not include your misbehaving port.

Comment: I've never seen a Windows firewall software that allows you to block on `localhost`, as `localhost` is not a recognised adapter. Any suggestions on which one I can try? Same goes for TCP/IP filtering - the localhost adapter doesn't really "exist"

Comment: gimme a day or two to confirm this. I have to build a win2003 test machine for something else anyway.